# push notification is not working on windows server 2008 R2

Tags: android, push-notification, windows-server-2008-r2

Android push notification is not working on widows server (**windows server 2008 R2**) But the same code is working on my local machine, also I am getting push messages to my device. I am using server api key of my Google Developer console. In that allowed IP's are **Any IP allowed**. Now I am gerring an error "authentication failed".

Here is my code.

```
 string AndroidAPI = GetConfig("AndroidAPI");
 string message = MessageText;
 push.RegisterGcmService(new GcmPushChannelSettings(AndroidAPI));//server api key
 var obj = new { alert = message, badge = 7 };
 var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
 string jsonMessage = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);

 GcmNotification().ForDeviceRegistrationId(RegId).WithJson(jsonMessage)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11942736/failed-gcm-registration-in-android